# How do I deal with empty list items while scraping web data?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data into a CSV file from a website that lists contact information for people in my industry. My code works well until I get to a page where one of the entries doesn't have a specific item.

So for example:

I'm trying to collect

Name, Phone, Profile URL

If there isn't a phone number listed, there isn't even a tag for that field on the page, and my code errors out with

"IndexError: list index out of range"

I'm pretty new to this, but what I've managed to cobble together so far from various youtube tutorials/this site has really saved me a ton of time completing some tasks that would take me days otherwise. I'd appreciate any help that anyone is willing to offer.

I've tried varying if/then statements where if the variable is null, then set the variable to "Empty"

## Edit:

I updated the code. I switched to CSS Selectors for more specificity and readability. I also added a try/except to at least bypass the index error, but doesn't solve the problem of incorrect data being stored due to uneven amounts of data for each field. Also, the site I'm trying to scrape is in the code now.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
driver = webdriver.Firefox()


MAX_PAGE_NUM = 5
MAX_PAGE_DIG = 2

with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Name, Number, URL \n")

#Run Through Pages
for i in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM + 1):
    page_num = (MAX_PAGE_DIG - len(str(i))) * "0" + str(i)
    website = "https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/lansing_mi/pg-" + page_num
    driver.get(website)

    Name = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.agent-list-card-title-text.clearfix > div.agent-name.text-bold > a')
    Number = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.agent-list-card-title-text.clearfix > div.agent-phone.hidden-xs.hidden-xxs')
    URL = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.agent-list-card-title-text.clearfix > div.agent-name.text-bold > a')

#Collect Data From Each Page
    num_page_items = len(Name)
    with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
        for i in range(num_page_items):
            try:
                f.write(Name[i].text.replace(",", ".") + "," + Number[i].text + "," + URL[i].get_attribute('href') + "\n")
                print(Name[i].text.replace(",", ".") + "," + Number[i].text + "," + URL[i].get_attribute('href') + "\n")
            except IndexError:
                f.write("Skip, Skip, Skip \n")
                print("Number Missing")
                continue


driver.close()
```

If any of the fields I'm trying to collect don't exist on individual listings, I just want the empty field to be filled in as "Empty" on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Have you tried try/except blocks? If not, look into them. Using this block, if a part of your code will give an error, it will instead run whatever is in the except part.

Comment: I'm actually trying that right now. Not having much luck so far. 

I think the key is with NoSuchElementException along with a try/except block, but I can't seem to make it fire.

Comment: The problem is that the indexError will always be at the end of your list. Eg if you have 3 names, with 2 numbers and it is the first name which have not a number, the first name will have the second number, the second name will have the third number and the third name will raise an indexError, but your entire data will be corrupted. Maybe you can share with us the url to have a better example and solution

Comment: @FakeHelicopterPilot Good if you update your code with try/except changes you made. Also, if you can add error logs that would help address your problem.

Comment: @Maaz Thanks for elaborating on that a little.

I'm trying to scrape is [a list of realtors](https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/lansing_mi/pg-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use try/except to take care of that. I also opted to use Pandas and BeautifulSoup as I'm more familiar with those.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
import pandas as pd

MAX_PAGE_NUM = 5
MAX_PAGE_DIG = 2

results = pd.DataFrame()
#Run Through Pages
for i in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM + 1):
    page_num = (MAX_PAGE_DIG - len(str(i))) * "0" + str(i)
    website = "https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/lansing_mi/pg-" + page_num
    driver.get(website)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    agent_cards = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'agent-list-card clearfix'})

    for agent in agent_cards:

        try:
            Name = agent.find('div', {'itemprop':'name'}).text.strip().split('\n')[0]
        except:
            Name = None

        try:
            Number = agent.find('div', {'itemprop':'telephone'}).text.strip()
        except:
            Number = None

        try:
            URL = 'https://www.realtor.com/' + agent.find('a', href=True)['href']
        except:
            URL = None

        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[Name, Number, URL]], columns=['Name','Number','URL'])
        results = results.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
    print('Processed page: %s' %i)

driver.close()

results.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
                                   Name  ...                                                URL
0                            Nicole Enz  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/nico...
1                  Jennifer Worthington  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/jenn...
2                      Katherine Keener  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/kath...
3                            Erica Cook  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/eric...
4   Jeff Thornton, Broker, Assoc Broker  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/jeff...
5                   Neal Sanford, Agent  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/neal...
6                           Sherree Zea  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/sher...
7                       Jennifer Cooper  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/jenn...
8                      Charlyn Cosgrove  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/char...
9          Kathy Birchen & Chad Dutcher  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/kath...
10                        Nancy Petroff  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/nanc...
11              The Angela Averill Team  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/the-...
12                  Christina Tamburino  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/chri...
13                      Rayce O'Connell  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/rayc...
14                      Stephanie Morey  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/step...
15                         Sean Gardner  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/sean...
16                            John Burg  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/john...
17                Linda Ellsworth-Moore  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/lind...
18                         David Bueche  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/davi...
19                       David Ledebuhr  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/davi...
20                            Aaron Fox  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/aaro...
21                       Kristy Seibold  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/kris...
22                        Genia Beckman  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/geni...
23                         Angela Bolan  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/ange...
24                      Constance Benca  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/cons...
25                            Lisa Fata  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/lisa...
26                          Mike Dedman  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/mike...
27                        Jamie Masarik  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/jami...
28                           Amy Yaroch  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/amy-...
29                      Debbie McCarthy  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/debb...
..                                  ...  ...                                                ...
70                      Vickie Blattner  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/vick...
71                      Faith F Steller  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/fait...
72                      A.  Jason Titus  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/a.--...
73                            Matt Bunn  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/matt...
74                           Joe Vitale  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/joe-...
75                   Reozom Real Estate  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/reoz...
76                        Shane Broyles  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/shan...
77                   Megan Doyle-Busque  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/mega...
78                         Linda Holmes  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/lind...
79                           Jeff Burke  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/jeff...
80                        Jim Convissor  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/jim-...
81                  Concetta D'Agostino  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/conc...
82                     Melanie McNamara  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/mela...
83                          Julie Adams  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/juli...
84                          Liz Horford  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/liz-...
85                         Miriam Olsen  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/miri...
86                       Wanda Williams  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/wand...
87                         Troy Seyfert  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/troy...
88                        Maggie Gerich  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/magg...
89                 Laura Farhat Bramson  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/laur...
90                      Peter MacIntyre  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/pete...
91                        Mark Jacobsen  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/mark...
92                             Deb Good  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/deb-...
93                 Mary Jane Vanderstow  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/mary...
94                           Ben Magsig  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/ben-...
95                   Brenna Chamberlain  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/bren...
96                  Deborah Cooper, CNS  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/debo...
97            Huggler, Bashore & Brooks  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/hugg...
98             Jodey Shepardson Custack  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/jode...
99              Madaline Alspaugh-Young  ...  https://www.realtor.com//realestateagents/mada...

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Nice answer, I definitely have to learn more about pandas. Anyway, I still don't know why I was not be able to get all the data by page (using bs4 and selenium I was only able to get 14 elements, sometimes 1 per page :-/ )

Comment: I love pandas. People have given me grief with it sometimes saying it's sort of overkill...but honestly, I just feel comfortable with it, and performance wise it hasn't really affected anything. And Ya I have no idea why you'd only get a limited return of the data. What versions of python, Selenium and bs4 you using?

Comment: 3.6.8, 3.8.0 and 4.6.0, and my code was clearly same of yours, even the `agent_cards` variable name ^^

Comment: @chitown88 holy crap, thank you so much for taking the time to answer this. Works really great and is much faster.

Comment: @Maaz, I'm using 3.6.7, 3.141.0, 4.6.3. Doesnt seem like that would be the issue. I have no clue

Comment: Shouldnt you try also http i noticed sometimes https fail in some sites